# Supermicro X8DT3/X8DTi hardisk not found after installing OS

Tags: installation, supermicro, operating-system

I try to install Linux CentOS in server Supermicro X8DT3/X8DTi. Installation proccessed succesfully, but after server rebooting, server cannot boot into OS. When I check BIOS, no hardisk found on boot priority. I'm counfuse what's the problem, Hardisk detected when installing OS, but now is gone x_x

Thanks.

Comment: this is not related to linux, could be that hard drive died... coincidence ?

Comment: I've tried with another hard drive, but the result is same. sorry for the title :D

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by 'no hardisk found on boot priority'. I'm interested if BIOS can see the drive at all after the install.

Comment: yes, I did not find the hard drive in the boot settings in the BIOS, only cd room. when I try to reboot again, I get message "reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

Comment: Sounds like some bios issue; make sure you update BIOS to latest version

Answer (score 0):

> Hardisk detected when installing OS, but no hardisk found on boot priority

There is a SATA section in bios settings, make sure SATA ports are not disabled.